# Failing to implement Firebase Phone Auth on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

hey so I have a function Firebase/iOS app and am trying to implement phone auth.

- pods are installed
- APNs authentication key uploaded to Firebase
- Push notifs enabled in Xcode
- calling this method

  `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
    if let error = error {
      self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
      return
    }
    // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
    // ...
  }`

in the view controller and passing a valid number.

I get this error ->

> The UIApplicationDelegate must handle remote notification for phone number authentication to work.
>
> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17054 "If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method., error_name=ERROR_NOTIFICATION_NOT_FORWARDED}

**Swizzling** is not disabled not that I know of. Delegate doesn't have much goin on but this walkthrough https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth didn't mention it.

I'm not getting the silent notification I assume and def not receiving an SMS.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing on a physical device? If so, try running the app again without Xcode debugger (run without Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in your `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }
    // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    handleNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: hi this works in that a notification is seemingly received. this notification as written in the method above as 'notification' can be printed the console as
[AnyHashable("com.google.firebase.auth"): {
    warning = "This fake notification should be forwarded to Firebase Auth.";
}]

and no error is thrown. however an sms is still not sent. I also have to comment out the 'handleNotification' method for it to run as there is no 'handleNotification' method Xcode can find